# PostgreSQL subquery with syntax error gives a valid result

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, syntax-error

What is happening here?

I got two tables, test1 and test2:

```
create table test1 (id1 int4 primary key);
create table test2 (id2 int4 primary key);
```

As expected, this query:

```
select id1 from test2;
```

produces a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  column "id1" does not exist
LINE 1: select id1 from test2;
```

However, when I try to execute this query:

```
select * from test1 where id1 in (select id1 from test2);
```

PostgreSQL doesn't complain, executes the query and gives me:

```
 id1
-----
(0 rows)
```

Is there any logic in this? Or should I file a bug report?

Comment: Aside: I'd use the the generally superior `WHERE EXISTS ()` instead of `WHERE col IN ()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Columns from outer `select` are visible in sub-select.

Your query is equivalent to:

```
select * 
from test1 
where test1.id1 in (select test1.id1 from test2);
```

Comment: Ok, so if table test1 contains a single value 42, the subquery is interpreted as "select 42 from test2", which is valid sql?

Comment: Tnx :) Just got a real life example of this behavior and it confused the hell out of me :)