# Why is Postgres not raising an error in a subquery when there is an error?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table **user** and table **message**:

- Table user contains the following columns: (id, first_name, last_name)
- Table message contains the following columns: (id, message, date, owner)

Owner is a foreign key to the id of the user that wrote the message.

When I run this query, I get no errors, but it returns ALL the users.

```
select *
from user
where id in
(
    select non_existing_column
    from message
    where date > '2017-01-01'
);
```

Why doesn't it return an error, when in the subquery I am trying to select a non-existing column?

Comment: please update tables structure to smth reproducible eg: `select 1 where 1 <> (select non_existing_column from pg_proc where oid <0 )` gives an 
 error as supposed

Comment: Provide sample data set to produce mentioned issue

Comment: Are you sure that "non_existing_column" doesn't belong to the user table? Tip of today: qualify your columns! (E.g. `message.non_existing_column`.)

Comment: There is an answer to this here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407023/postgresql-subquery-with-syntax-error-gives-a-valid-result